# EF5 How to Add missing Relationships

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi i have a database first EF5 model defined. 
My user table has a primary key guid UserGUID 
and another key field UserID with an auto-incrementing integer. 
I have created a table called UserCustomField which has 
UserID and I have created a foreign key constraint to UserID in my User Table.

When I update the model from the database all foreign key relationships to primary keys are generated but none to Key fields. Ignoring the potential point about using the guid through all my tables.....
A/ shouldn't EF add this relationship?
B/ how can i manually add it?

Cheers
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A: No.
B: You cannot.

EF is able to use relations only when they point to primary key so either change `User` table to use `UserID` as primary key and remove `UserGuid` or change `UserCustomField` table to point `UserID` to `UserGuid` in the `User` table.

The reason why it doesn't work is that your database requires `UserID` in `User` table to be marked as unique (that means unique constraint) and EF doesn't support unique constraints yet.

Comment: Is it not possible for me to add my own property at least to the user object, so i can do the equivalent of foreach(UserCustomField item in myUser.UserCustomerFields())

Comment: If you don't modify your model to create relation in EDMX you will have to hide your own Linq query with manual join behind that new property. That will make your User entity dependent on EF's context instance.

Comment: Sorry Ladislav, i couldn't workout what you are conveying in your comment. Are you saying this isn't desirable? I couldn't see an obvious place to add the method or property on my user object as EF appears to populate classes which have no knowledge of context.